# How to join two tables with different number of rows?

Tags: laravel

I have two tables. One is about product specifications containing about 500 products. The second table is about 50 products pertaining to profit. I want to extract those 50 products from the table containing 500 products. And display both specifications and profit of the 50 products in a single table.

I tried to use  whereIn and join in a single statement but it showed "Integrity Constraint violation".

Answer (score 0):

Using a join should be enough to  do this:

```
DB::table('table_with_50_products')
    ->join('table_with_50_products as t50', 'id', '=', 'table_with_500_products.id')
    ->select('t50.*', 'table_with_500_products.specifications')
    ->get();
```

**edit**
added table alias

Comment: there now it should be fixed.

Comment: Getting column not found.

Comment: I don't know what your table columns are named, those are only examples. If you post your table schema I can update my answer.

Comment: I know you are giving examples. For table with 500 products: name, ucp, updcp,.... for table with 50 products: name, value, pp.

Comment: Which column is not found?

Comment: I only added one column of ucp.

Comment: When you got the `Column not found` error, which one did it say?

Comment: when I tried to execute the controller method. And the ucp one only.

Comment: If it is proving too much work for you, it is okay. I am not a professional programmer. I can do this in excel.

Comment: It's just not clear what the error is, typically mysql reports errors that give both the table name and the column, as well as an excerpt of the query where it failed. If that could be provided it would be very useful.

Comment: Here is the error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'spe.ucp' in 'field list' (SQL: select `pre`.*, `spe`.`ucp` from `pre` inner join `pre` as `t50` on `name` = `spe`.`name`)

Comment: So `table_with_50_products` is named `pre` and `table_with_500_products` is named `spe`? Does the column `ucp` exist on `spe`? Also I see you changed `id` to `name`, do you not have numeric primary keys?

Comment: yes, t500 is spe and t50 is pre. ucp does exist on spe. No, I don't have any numeric primary keys.

Comment: try switching the `join` around like this `->join('table_with_500_products as t500', 'id', '=', 'table_with_5000_products.id')`